# Create a VM from an image

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

How can I create a virtual machine based on previous image in Microsoft Azure ?

I went to their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-generalized-managed) but it wasn't helpful to me, because after clicking "all resources" I cannot see the images that I captured.

Edit:

is there any way to do it using their GUI and not by power-Shell and how

Edit 2:
This is what I got after clicking all resources:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to do it using their GUI and not by power-Shell and
>   how

Yes, you could do it on Azure Portal. Like below:

[image]

If you don't see image in it. It means you don't create image for your VM. You should create image firstly. Yes, you could create image on Portal. But you need generalize your VM, see this [link:Prepare VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-custom-images#prepare-vm).

Comment: Hi, do you find your image in Azure Portal?

Comment: Please let me know if you need more future help.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer!, could you please right the steps how did you reach to images?, did you clicked on all resources?

Comment: I've edited my answer and added a screenshot

Comment: According to the screenshot, there is no image in your subscription. You could filter it only show images, like this https://imgur.com/a/F4Urh If you don't find images, you should create it firstly.

Comment: @Hanin Hi, do you find your VM's image. If you don't find it. Create one on Portal. it is very easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score -1):

First create a managed image of a generalized VM and the click all resources to find the created images.

**Note:** You need to have already [created a managed VM image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource) to use for creating the new VM.